# Is there CSS style to select an element that has any id?

Tags: html, css

I have html documents where I want to target h2 tags that have any id value and not target h2 that have no id. I know rewriting the html with classes is a possible option, but trying to only change the CSS right now.

I want to target the following with a css rule:

```
<h2 id="one">
<h2 id="two">
```

but not target the following at the same time

```
<h2>
```

Is there something like

```
h2#[*] { font-size: 12pt}
```

that would accomplish this? I've searched on this site and others and haven't found the answer. I'm sure this is basic CSS for many here but I'm stumped.
Thanks, MB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a CSS attribute-selector, selecting only elements that have a specific attribute present, such as – as in your question – the `id`:

```
h1[id], h2[id] {
  /* CSS rules */
}
```

```css
h1[id],
h2[id] {
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading level 1, with no id</h1>
<h1 id="h1">Heading level 1, with an id</h1>

<h2>Heading level 2, with no id</h1>
<h2 id="h2">Heading level 2, with an id</h1>
```

References:

- [CSS Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: This does not guarantee that the `id` attribute has a value, just that it is present. The question states "that have any id value" ...  using the negation pseudo-class is recommended: `h1[id]:not([id=""]) {  }`.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use attribute selector in css

`[id]{
/* css here */
}`

this will select any element with **id** attribute

for your case you need `h2[id]`

working example here http://jsbin.com/fabayaqusa/edit?html,css,output